# Windows cannot find 'delete'

Tags: command-line, windows-vista

When I try to run this command in my Windows Vista Tablet PC `delete "c:\Users\RandyFujitsu\Music\Podcasts\Morning Edition\*.mp3"`, I get this error:

**Windows cannot find 'delete'**

Comment: It's called `del`.

Comment: i just tried del "c:\Users\RandyFujitsu\Music\Podcasts\Morning Edition\\*.mp3" and i get the error message Windows cannot find 'del'...

Comment: What is the output when you run `echo %PATH%`?  How are you running these commands?

Comment: @Breakthrough: That's the error the Run dialog returns. I would say Jim's answer below is probably correct, unless the OP can confirm he's entering this at the cmd prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running at a command prompt, the command you want is `del`.  From the comments, it sounds like you might be typing this in the "Run" or Search box.  Open up a command prompt (Start->Run-> type in `cmd` ), then try the `del` command.

Comment: This is most likely the correct reason.

Comment: `erase` will also work.